# significance of "Object" data type in an object

Tags: java

```
public final class Mess {
Object obj1 ;
// rest of the codes
......
```

please explain to me,for i'm a beginner, what is the significance of Object boj1?
in some codes I've found that a for the same object "mess" they use,

```
mess obj = new mess();
```

I've understood this one but I am quite not sure what type of variable (or might be refrence) does the code `Object obj1`  create..,

Comment: Always use Java naming conventions, even in examples. Classes are in `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Because you have not given any details, you are essentially asking us to rewrite part of your textbook for you, when presumably you already have a textbook or course notes but just haven't read far enough in it yet. This is rather rude, it's like asking us "please teach me Java for free". You could at least provide some more context from that code so we could give an answer specific to that code and what it was doing, or ask about some specific text in your textbook or course notes that you didn't understand; that would probably be more helpful to you as well.

Comment: What I mean is, this is not a site to teach you basic Java, there are other sites, and courses, for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classes that you create in Java, like `Mess`, are subclasses of `Object`.

When you write a class as following:

```
public final class Mess {
```

To Java, it actually means the following (though you do not write the `extends` part):

```
public final class Mess extends Object {
```

When you create an object using the `Mess` class:

```
Mess myMess = new Mess();
```

This object can only be a `Mess` or a subclass of `Mess` (something that `extends Mess`). It cannot be a `String`, or any other class.

But when you create an object using the `Object` class:

```
Object myObj;
```

It can be anything that is a subclass of `Object`:

```
myObj = new String("I am awesome!");
myObj = new Mess();
```

But this doesn't mean that `myObj` will magically become a `String` or `Mess`. It will still be an `Object`, but it's referring to a `String` object or a `Mess` object.

If you need to refer to `myObj` as a `String` or a `Mess`, you will have to cast it **explicitly** (because, to the program, it's just an `Object`):

```
myObj = new String("I am awesome!");
myObj.toString(); //OK, it calls Object.toString
//myObj.substring(5, 12); //** COMPILE ERROR, there is no Object.substring
String myString = (String)myObj;
myString.substring(5, 12); //OK, it calls String.substring

myObj = new Mess();
//myObj.cleanItUp(); //** COMPILE ERROR, there is no Object.cleanItUp
Mess myMess = (Mess)myObj;
myMess.cleanItUp(); //OK, it calls Mess.cleanItUp
myString = (String)myObj; //** RUNTIME ERROR, myObj is not a String
```

You may also cast it like this:

```
myObj = new String("I am awesome!");
myObj.toString(); //OK, it calls Object.toString
//myObj.substring(5, 12); //** COMPILE ERROR, there is no Object.substring
((String)myObj).substring(5, 12); //OK, it calls String.substring

myObj = new Mess();
//myObj.cleanItUp(); //** COMPILE ERROR, there is no Object.cleanItUp
((Mess)myObj).cleanItUp(); //OK, it calls Mess.cleanItUp
((String)myObj).substring(5, 12); //** RUNTIME ERROR, myObj is not a String
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object` class is the parent class of all the classes in Java. As per Java inheritance syntax, a parent class reference can hold the instance of any of its subclasses. So Object type is used where it is required to hold any of its sublclass/any type. There are many usage of it for example Factory implementations.

Comment: May want to mention that every class in Java is a subclass of `Object`. And by extension, `mess` *extends* `Object` even though it's not declared as such.

Comment: @ADTC First sentence mentions it, isnt?

Comment: I know, but he's a beginner `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Object obj1 ;
```

It's just like any other instance member which can be a type Object. Now it can hold the any  Object as it's type is the super class of all Classes in java.

May be some where else in the code they can assign that variable with any class.

ex

```
Object obj1 = new String("");
```

But it's really smell like a flaw in design.

As it's type is Object and for sure one should have to cast to the respected object type to use it.